# if statement, selecting a class or an element

Tags: jquery, if-statement, element

For example I do have a .className and an element tag. If the user did not clicks on that className or the element tag the alert will run.

Please correct my code:

```
var i = $("ul li");
if (!$(this).hasClass("className") || !$(this) == i) {
 alert("Gotya!");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by clicking on a className or element tag?  Do you mean any element with the given class name or element name?

Comment: I just edited it. The choices are: ".className" OR "ul li"

Comment: you want to run alert on click of any element having class `.className` or on click of element tag or ob both

Comment: Both, when user DID NOT clicked on '.className' OR the 'ul li' tag then the alert will show

Comment: ohh!!!!!...i took it in opposite way..

Comment: `!$(this) == i` makes *no* sense. `$()` will always return a collection (possibly empty) which, when negated, is always `false`. I.e., `!$(this) == i` will *always* evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Oh wait, still confused.  Is it "all li elements that are both inside a ul element and *do not* have a specified class?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you wont the alert to run if element "className" or "ul li" is clicked?

Then you should use jquerys event click http://api.jquery.com/click/ and multiple selectors http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

For example:

```
$(".className, ul li").click(function() {
alert("Click event was fired");
});
```

If that is not your question, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

remove `!` this...

```
if ($(this).hasClass("className") || $(this) == i) {
     alert("Gotya!");
    }
```

or you can try this also-

```
$('.className, ul li').live('click', function(){
alert("Gotya!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, because you are asking to run the click handler if either an element with a particular name *or* a particular class is clicked, you are probably wondering whether the "," used in CSS selectors will work in jQuery.  It does work, as Vivek's answer shows.  You can probably get away without the "live" call, though and just use:

```
$("ul li, .className").click(function () {alert("Gotya");});
```

Comment: `var gotya = alert("Gotya");` will just show an alert and assign undefined to `gotya`, no? Didn't you mean `var gotya = function() { alert("Gotya"); };`?

Comment: i think your also interpreted OP in wrong way, he want to do same but when user not clicked on specified element in question.. :)

Comment: @Shurdoof Absolutely.  Hit Post Answer button prematurely.  Edited answer to credit Vivek, too.